# Modal fade effect not working on Bootstrap 4.1 or higher

Tags: bootstrap-4, fade

If I go to modal examples page to 4.1 or higher in my PC
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal
and click to this button to open the modal...

[Modal examples page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUa4N.png)

The modal appears directly without any fade animation, even if I try clear the cache using (win + R) or using CCleaner but it works in my other devices...

Now I realized that it works if I use bootstrap 4.0 or lower...

I don't know if it's important but I recently formatted the PC but I'm sure it has all its drivers.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I've realized that I have also problem using facebook in this computer, when I'm playing a video I usually use right click on it to copy its url and now nothing happens when I use right click on any facebook video.

Comment: Perhaps a good place to post this is Bootstrap's issue tracker?